# Permutations of UNIVERSAL

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many of permutations of word UNIVERSAL, no two of the letters E, R, S occur together.

I'm confused while proceeding with this one, I know total permutation is 9!.

Comment: This is an inclusion-exclusion problem. Count the combos where ER, RS, ES are together, subtract those, and add the ones where ERS are together.

Answer (score 3):

The task to arrange the letters can be performed by

- Permuting the six letters UNIVAL.
- Permuting the three letters ERS.
- Merging the second string into the first by selecting three spaces from the seven between (and around) those of first string.

  - thusly each letter of the second string will be separated by at least one letter in the first.

...count the ways...